# fasttext - Extracting and comparing pre-trained word vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, text, fasttext

I'm working with the German pre-trained word vectors from https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md

I encountered the following problems:

1. To extract the vectors for my words, I started by simply searching the `wiki.de.vec` text-file for the respective words. However, vectors in the `wiki.de.vec` text-file differ from those that the `print-word-vectors` function outputs (e.g. the vector for 'affe' meaning 'monkey' is different in the `wiki.de.vec` file than the output for 'affe' from `print-word-vectors`). What is the reason for this? I assume this occurs because the vector for a word is computed by adding the sum of its character *n*-gram vectors in the model by Bojanowski et al., but what does the vector for 'affe' in the `wiki.de.vec` text-file reflect then? Is it the vector for the *n*-gram 'affe' that also occurs in other words like 'karaffe'. So, should one always use the `print-word-vectors` function (i.e. add the character *n*-gram vectors) when working with these vectors and *not* simply extract vectors from the text-file?
2. Some real German words (e.g. knatschen, resonieren) receive a null vector (even with the `print-word-vectors` function). How can this be if the major advantage of this subword approach is to compute vectors for out-of-vocabulary words?
3. The nearest-neighbors function (`./fasttext nn`) outputs the nearest-neighbors of a word with the cosine distance. However, this value differs from the value I obtain by getting the vectors of the individual words with `print-word-vectors` and computing their cosine distance manually in Matlab using `pdist2(wordVector1, wordVector2, 'cosine')`. Why is this the case? Is this the wrong way to obtain the cosine distance between two word vectors?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Did you find any answers to above questions? @Phil K